# How to start play current level in a Unreal Engine plugin C++ code?

Tags: unreal-engine5

I want to start to play the current level in a UE5 plugin, just like press the "Play" button on the toolbar. I've created a plugin based on the "Editor Toolbar Button" template, but I can't find APIs related to Play or Stop the current level.

Any helpful discussions or suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `UEditorEngine::RequestPlaySession(const FRequestPlaySessionParams& InParams)` and `UEditorEngine::TeardownPlaySession(FWorldContext& PieWorldContext)`?